# Как закрепить выбранные по фильтру значения на сводной диаграмме, чтобы посмотреть их исторические данные?

Tags: excel

Я использую сводную диаграмму. Есть категории периодов (год\квартал\месяц), я суммирую значения по показателю для каждой компании (по фильтру выбираю первые 10 наибольших по сумме значений показателя). Вопрос в следующем: я хочу закрепить топ по текущему выбранному периоду, чтобы, изменив период, посмотреть исторические данные этого топа. Но получается, что при изменении периода диаграмма выдаёт топ компаний по сумме значений показателя уже за новый выбранный период.

Comment: Сводная выдает то, что у нее попросили. Естественно, что при изменении входных данных выходные тоже могут измениться. Нужно использовать другие инструменты. Например, VBA (макросы). *Возможно, не понял вопрос...*